# Anyone know how to get Live appID for paypal adaptive API?

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I am new here and wondering if anybody can help me?

I was looking for a Live appID for paypal to use the adaptive API as an escrow on my wordpress site.

I am uing a wordpress template and I only need this appID.

I have googled it and it seems that paypal have now changed there procedure for applying for verification. All the tutorial videos advise me to go to:
https://www.paypal-apps.com/user/my-accounts/applications

But when I go there is does not give me the opion to select "new app" and apply for adaptive app aplication.

It says that "this portal will be permanently unavailable as of December 1, 2017"

Can anybody tell me where I would apply for the AppID now?

Thanks in advance!

Jas

Answer (score 1):

The PayPal Adaptive Payments are no longer available. With regards to alternatives, please look at MarketPlaces. PayPal's MarketPlaces is open and you may test the product.

You may refer to the link below for more information.https://developer.paypal.com/docs/marketplaces/pp4mp/

If you would like to sign up, you can do so here : https://www.paypal.com/us/webapps/mpp/partner-program/contact-us?ref=marketplace

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

PayPal's Adaptive API is a now a limited release. You cannot apply for a live app ID anymore.

Quote from developer.paypal.com:

> "Important: Adaptive Payments is now a limited release product. It is
>   restricted to select partners for approved use cases and should not be
>   used for new integrations without guidance from PayPal."

I'm sure "Approved use cases" means your an enterprise level merchant with millions of transaction volume ;)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, Adaptive Payments is not being approved in most cases any more.  It's better to use billing agreements / reference transactions.

They are releasing a new system called Marketplaces before long, but it's not quite ready yet.